# Prove that $T(f(t))=f′(t)+3f(t)$ from $C^∞$ to $C^∞$ is or isn't a linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

> Is $T(f(t))=f′(t)+3f(t)$ from $C^∞$ to $C^∞$ a linear transformation?

I know to find a linear transformation you have to see if it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Also, apparently I cannot use a concrete example to disprove this. However, I have no idea how to represent the functions and the linear transformation where I can simply add on addition or scalar multiplication. This is what I got so far.

$$ A = \{ f(t)_1, ..., f(t)_n \}$$
$$T(A) = \{ f'(t)_1 + 3f(t)_1, ..., f'(t)_n + 3f(t)_n \}$$
$$B = \{ g(t)_1, ..., g(t)_n \}$$
$$T(B) = \{ g'(t)_1 + 3g(t)_1, ..., g'(t)_n + 3g(t)_n \}$$
Then simply test for $T(A+B)=T(A)+T(B)$ and that $T(cA)=cT(A)$.

Am I not supposed to test for an entire set of elements like this?

Comment: Hint: write down $T(\lambda f(t) + \mu g(t))$ and compare against $\lambda T(f(t)) + \mu T(g(t))$.

Comment: I think you really want to check the definition of "linear transformation" and the definition of "vector subspace".

Comment: You want to do what you suggest with the additional hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are singletons. That's the definition of linear maps (and it turns out to be equivalent to what you are trying to do, though it's quite an uncanny way to see it).

Comment: Should I do $A=f(t)$ and $B=g(t)$? I assumed I needed a set of all functions applicable to test for all of them.

Comment: all you need to write is  $\forall f,g \in C^\infty$ and $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ :  $T(f+g)(t) =  f'(t)+g'(t)+3f(t)+3g(t) = T(f)(t)+T(g)(t)$ and $T(af)(t) = a f'(t)+3a f(t)=a\,T(f)(t)$